# how to select substring from concatenated filed?

Tags: sql, substring

I have a requirement where i want to get substring of a concatenated column in database. The length can be vary for different records but pattern will be same.
Example :
I want to get value as `4306657|AA-BB-CC-XX-10|5194|` from column value `4306657|AA-BB-CC-XX-10|5194|BILLING`.
What will be the select statement or function ?

Comment: suggestion: split in programing language php/ruby/perl/.net then in sql if it is not to be passed on to next sql query.
Also if you are concatenating a string, why concatinate that part which is to be read separately

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTRING` function in mysql.
Here is the syntax of that function

```
SUBSTRING(str, pos, len)
```

where
str = input string,
pos = An integer indicating a string position within the string str,
len = An integer indicating number of characters to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
DECLARE @TEST VARCHAR(1000)
SET @TEST = '4306657|AA-BB-CC-XX-10|5194|BILLING'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@TEST,1,LEN(@TEST)-CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE(@TEST),1)+1)
```